# XML Attribute In Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

```
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="TheMainElement" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Attribute1OrAttribute2">
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I have the created the above XSD for an output of the following XML:

```
<TheMainElement Attribute1OrAttribute2="Attribute1">Text</TheMainElement>
```

From the java coding perspective, I understand the element creation and if I attempted the same for the attribute too, it would have an end bracket as that too.

```
Element TheMainElement = document.createElement("TheMainElement");
```

How can I add the Attribute part without it appearing in the end bracket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `org.w3c.dom.Element#setAttribute(String name, String value)`

So in your case it would be

```
TheMainElement.setAttribute("Attribute1OrAttribute2", "Attribute1");
```

Depending on your needs, you can also have a look at the `org.w3c.dom.Element#setAttributeNode(Attr newAttr)`. You would have to implement the `Attr` interface or use a dedicated library that already provides some implementation such as [dom4j](https://dom4j.github.io/), which will also help you to create a manipulate XML documents.

As a side note, i would personnally discourage the use of variable with the first letter capitalized , the standard would be to use lower camel case `TheMainElement -> theMainElement`
See the [google java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.7-local-variable-names) for example

Comment: Thank you! This is the help I needed. Very clear! :)

Comment: Another similar clarification, if I wanted more attributes, do I just add it to additional brackets?
Would the following... 
`TheMainElement.setAttribute("Attribute1OrAttribute2", "Attribute1", "Extra", "AnotherAttribute");`

Produce this...
`<TheMainElement Attribute1OrAttribute2="Attribute1" Extra="AnotherAttribute">Text</TheMainElement>`

Comment: As stated in [the documentation of this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
> If an attribute with that name is already present in the element, its value is changed to be that of the value parameter.

Comment: To add several attributes with different name, you must call the `setAttribute` method several times. `TheMainElement.setAttribute("Attribute1OrAttribute2", "Attribute1");` then `TheMainElement.setAttribute("extra", "value");`